# Publishing failing in final stage of workflow

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Our final automatic activity is publishing component to live target. We have below code written in Edit script.

```
' Script for Automatic Activity Content Manager Workflow

Set oTDSE = CreateObject("TDS.TDSE")
Call oTDSE.Initialize
Set oWorkItem = CurrentWorkItem.GetItem(3)
sDestinationServer = "tcm:0-18-65538"
Set oComp = oTDSE.GetObject(oWorkItem.ID, 3) 

Call oComp.Publish(sDestinationServer, True, True, True)

FinishActivity "Automatic Activity ""Process Complete"" Finished"

set oWorkItem = Nothing
set oComp = Nothing
set oTDSE = Nothing
```

This code is executing successfully but when we check publishing queue component is getting failed with error The item tcm:34-20615-16-v0 does not exist.

Same code is working fine when we are publishing the component to staging in earlier activity.

Comment: Thanks for your question, could we interest you in committing to the [Area 51 Tridion specific proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=gPujQMxthNCNn9xqeeO2NA2). Sign up with the same SO account if you have a moment.

Comment: Please update this question and accept your answer so this question can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that while in the script you are publishing dynamic version (-v0) of component. As publishing is asynchronous operation, item is not published straightaway, but publish transaction is created (which is linking to dynamic version).

After this, your script is done and item get checked-in. Now, publisher is starting with processing your publish transaction and discovers that there's no dynamic version anymore, hence your exception.

When publish activity is not last, publisher has enough time to get dynamic version of an item.

Workaround can be to wait for publish transaction to complete in your automatic activity, or do something with OnCheckIn event

Comment: Can't you just publish the non-dynamic version of the object? (remove the -v0 from the API)

Comment: @NunoLinhares I was considering adding this as an option, but then you might end up with the opposite problem - publishing latest checked-in version, before workflow will check it in, i.e. publishing old version

Comment: Hmm... interesting issue. I would expect others to have had this problem, seems very generic to have a publish action as the last step in a workflow...

Comment: I tried publishing workitem directly still the same error.      Call oWorkItem.Publish(sDestinationServer, True, True, True)

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is frequent one I faced at clients place. Especially when your last activity in workflow is automatic and  Publish to Live.
Simplest way I did is:

- First FinishActivity in automatic code
- Then Publish `workflow=false`.

```
PublishCoreServiceClient.FinishActivity(activityInstance.Id, finishData, publishoptions);           
            }

 //Now Publish      
ComponentData component = (ComponentData)PublishCoreServiceClient.Read(componentid, publishoptions);
if (GetConfigurationValues(component, PublishCoreServiceClient))
{
    PublishInstructionData publishInstructionData = new PublishInstructionData();
    publishInstructionData.MaximumNumberOfRenderFailures = 100;
    publishInstructionData.RollbackOnFailure = true;

    ResolveInstructionData resolveInstructionData = new ResolveInstructionData();
    resolveInstructionData.IncludeWorkflow = false;
    resolveInstructionData.IncludeChildPublications = true;
    resolveInstructionData.IncludeComponentLinks = true;
    publishInstructionData.ResolveInstruction = resolveInstructionData;

    RenderInstructionData renderInstructionData = new RenderInstructionData();
    publishInstructionData.RenderInstruction = renderInstructionData;

    List<string> ItemToPublish = new List<string>();
    ItemToPublish.Add(component.Id);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Utilities.LIVE_URI))
    {
        PublicationTargetData pubtarget = (PublicationTargetData)PublishCoreServiceClient.Read(Utilities.LIVE_URI, publishoptions);
        List<string> target = new List<string>();
        target.Add(pubtarget.Id);

        PublishCoreServiceClient.Publish(ItemToPublish.ToArray(), publishInstructionData, target.ToArray(), PublishPriority.Normal, publishoptions);
        Logger.Debug("ElapsedMilliseconds Publish [" + _watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms]");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved after setting activateWorkflow parameter of Publish method to False.

Comment: Be careful with that - are you sure it is not publishing your previous version?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same error and we have solved it by sending the component to publish with a few seconds delay:

```
Call oComp.Publish("tcm:0-1-65538", False, False, True, dateAdd("s",10,Now))
```